# Custom styles for Word in a Office Addin

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Im currently developing a Office addin and i want to create custom styles for user to style their texts with.
Can i create custom styles in general?
Can i create custom styles that show in the styles part of the ribbon?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score -1):

The Word JavaScript library does not support programmatic creation of custom styles at this time.

Comment: Can i create custom styles another way?

Comment: They can be created by the end users in Word. Your code can use the `styles` property to manage them to some extent.

Comment: @RickKirkham this is Possible
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.style?view=word-js-preview#word-word-style-set-member(1)

Comment: @MJunaid That is a way to update a style object programmatically, but not a way to create a new one programmatically, which is what the OP was asking for. The StyleCollection property doesn't have an `add` method.

Comment: If anyone reading this knows a way to programmatically create a custom style, don't just make a comment on another answer. Create your own answer and include a complete `Word.run` method that creates a custom style.